# How to create table in database for entity, using Spring JPA and Maven?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

How to generate table in the Postgres database for the entity below? I'm using maven build.

Entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "EMPLOYEE")
public class Employee {
   @Id @GeneratedValue
   @Column(name = "id")
   private int id;
}
```

properties:

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.cache.region.factory_class=org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegionFactory         
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5433/con_db        
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=root        
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.default_schema=as2
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy=com.ds.entity.strategy.EntityNamingStrategy
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true                
spring.jpa.show-sql=true        
spring.h2.console.enabled=true          
logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL=DEBUG  
logging.level.org.hibernate.type=TRACE
```

Comment: please mention the error that you got

Comment: my maven build is success , but the issue is after maven build when i open postgres DB tables are not generated

Comment: you have to run the spring boot app to build your database structure in the postgres database, there is no relation of maven with that

Comment: @Spartan thanks much, i was new to java so confused on build and start of application. thanks am able to create tables after running the application.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `hibernate default_schema` to `public` instead of `as2` like this: `spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.default_schema=public` then run your project.

Answer (score 0):

you have to run the spring boot app to build your database structure in the postgres database, there is no relation of maven with that. Thanks @Spartan for your help here.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).